# Characteristic curves for second-order Tricomi equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations, linear-pde

> Consider the [Tricomi equation](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Tricomi_equation)
>   $$yu_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$$
>   Find ordinary differential equations describing the *real* characteristic
>   curves and solve these ODEs to obtain equations for the characteristic
>   curves. Sketch the characteristic curves where they exist.

So Tricomi equation is hyperbolic if $y<0$, parabolic if $y=0$, elliptic if $y>0$. We need to find the *real* characteristics, so we need to look at the hyperbolic case $y<0$. From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Tricomi_equation), we can deduce that the characteristics for this equation are the curves $x \pm \frac{2}{3}(-y)^{3/2}=C$. How to derive the ODEs for characteristics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [linear second-order equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Linear_equations_of_second_order) rewrites as
$$
L[u] = a u_{xx} + 2bu_{xy} + c u_{yy} = 0
$$
where $a = y$, $b = 0$ and $c = 1$. Computing the *discriminant* $\Delta = b^2 - ac$ tells that the equation is hyperbolic if $\Delta = -y > 0$. We introduce the change of coordinates $(x,y) \mapsto (\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))$. To obtain the coordinates $\xi$, $\eta$ which reduce the PDE to its canonical form $w_{\xi\eta} = \ell[w]$, we solve the polynomial equation
$a \lambda^2 + 2b \lambda + c = 0$,
which roots are $\lambda = \pm (-y)^{-1/2}$. The characteristic equations are
$$
\frac{\text d x}{\text d t} = 1,
\qquad
\frac{\text d y}{\text d t} = -\lambda,
\qquad
\frac{\text d z}{\text d t} = 0 .
$$
Therefore, $\frac{\text d y}{\text d x} = \frac{\text d y/\text d t}{\text d x/\text d t} = \mp(-y)^{-1/2}$ gives the expected expression of characteristic curves, along which $\xi$ or $\eta$ is constant.

---

Further reading: p. 162-163 of

R. Courant, D. Hilbert: *Methods of Mathematical Physics* vol. II: "Partial differential equations". Wiley-VCH, 1962. [doi:10.1002/9783527617234](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/9783527617234)